Git History is missing for one file but changes are present when navigated from different file's history
Git History is missing for one file but changes are present when navigated from different file's history
Scenario:

let us consider initial commit as C1 having file src/A.csproj and some other files
After few days in Commit C100 we added one line in src/A.csproj and added new file X.cs

After 2 weeks at commit C200 we are facing issue in test server and noticed that new line added in src/A.csproj in C100 is missing. When I checked history of src/A.csproj there is only one commit C1. C100 is missing.
I checked X.cs file's history, here I can see C100 commit with src/A.csproj change also. But in src/A.csproj history there is only one initial commit C1.
I want to understand what happened here, why history is missing only for one file. I checked git log --full-history src/A.csproj, but did not understand, How to check.
Note: We are only using Visual Studio for all git operations.

One of the nice things about Git is that commits are immutable snapshots. If you run the command git show C100, it will either show the change to the .csproj file or it won't. And whatever it shows today, is how it's always been. So either your research is flawed today, or the change was never committed in C100 in the first place.

@TTT I have verified C100 multiple times, It has the change for .csproj.

OK. Can you confirm that C100 is actually in the history of your currently checked out HEAD? git rev-list HEAD and then make sure the commit ID of C100 shows up in that list. If you're using Git Bash it might be something like git rev-list HEAD | grep <commit-id-C100>. You could also substitute HEAD with C200 to make sure the histories are reachable. If the commit ID is in the history, then presumably another commit between C100 and C200 is removing the change.
